# Sort Order Column Dynamically Created From Another Column (Postgres)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to output a sort order column on a Postgres select query to give each row an order integer based the values of it's columns - with this sort order derived from another column.  Something like this:

```
select column_1_name, column_2_name, column_3_name, [a formula] AS sort_order 
from table_name
```

The data in the column `sort_order_column` would be a comma separated list of column names in the order I would like them to show in the sort_order (starting from 1 again for each unique item in the item column).

In the example below, I want to sort the 'car' items first by column_2_name, then by column_3_name. - this means the green car comes before the red car.

For boats, these are sorted first by column_1_name, then column_3_name, then finally by column_2_name.  This means the 10m boat comes before the 20m boat.

Data:
[image]

Desired output
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: sho thw code for  multiple columns  ..

Comment: What if the `sort_order_column` is different for every row that is returned? You can't have a different sort order for every row.

Comment: Question updated with clarification and a change to requirement.